# Passing NavLink state

Tags: reactjs, react-navigation

I am a Java developer and completely new to React and have a beginner issue with NavLink...

```
<Nav>
                <NavDropdown title="Budget" id="budget" replace="true" className="menu-test">
                  {openActPhases.map((item, index, openActPhases) => (
                    <Header item={item} openActPhases={openActPhases} index={index} />
                  ))}
                </NavDropdown>
</Nav>
```

And my Header component...

```
import * as React from "react";
import { NavLink, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import { Navbar, Container, Nav, Row, Col, NavDropdown } from "react-bootstrap";
import "./Header.scss"

const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState([]);

const Header = ({ item, openActPhases, index }) => {
    return <>
      <NavDropdown.Item>
        <Nav.Item key={item.id}>
          <NavLink key={item.id} to="/app/budget" replace="true" className="menu-test" >
            {item.label}
          </NavLink>
        </Nav.Item>
      </NavDropdown.Item>
    </>
};

export default Header;
```

My Route...

```
 <Route
    path="budget"
    element={
      <PrivateRoute>
        <ActiveSearch />
      </PrivateRoute>
    }
  />
```

Now I would like to fetch the label of the selected dropdown item on ActiveSearch component and display it on the redirected page and not sure how I could get that value. Any hints or pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the selected item's label as a parameter to the "to" prop in the **NavLink**. Then, you can access the parameter in the component rendered by the corresponding route. Here's how you can modify your code:

Update the **NavLink** in the **Header** component to include the label as a parameter:

```
 <NavLink
  key={item.id}
  to={`/app/budget/${encodeURIComponent(item.label)}`}
  replace={true}
  className="menu-test"
>
  {item.label}
</NavLink>
```

Update your Route to capture the label parameter:

```
  <Route
  path="budget/:label"
  element={
    <PrivateRoute>
      <ActiveSearch />
    </PrivateRoute>
  }
/>
```

Now, the **ActiveSearch** component can access the label parameter from the route's **params**:

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const ActiveSearch = () => {
  const { label } = useParams();

  // Now, 'label' contains the selected label from the NavLink

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Active Search</h1>
      <p>Selected Label: {label}</p>
      {/* Your other ActiveSearch component content */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ActiveSearch;
```